# Issue Deleting Google Compute Account through API using Python

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-python-api, google-cloud-iam

I was able to piece together a Python script to interact with the Google API Library using information from [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/iam_v1.projects.serviceAccounts.html#getIamPolicy) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy).  The code below is working and I'm able to list all accounts within a particular Project.  See below:

Code:

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from gcp import get_key

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = get_key()

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1')
project_id = 'test-buckets'

get_iam = {}

request = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body=get_iam)
response = request.execute()

bindings = response['bindings']

for binding in bindings:
    for member in binding['members']:
        print(member)
```

Output:

```
ssh://xxxx@x.x.x.x:22/home/xxxx/venv/bin/python3.4 -u /home/xxxx/scratch.py

serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
user:xxxx@.xxxxx.com
```

Now, I'm trying to leverage the API to delete specific accounts that are not needed (script below), however, I can't seem to get the the API to work.  I'm using the Google API Library again [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/iam_v1.projects.serviceAccounts.html#delete), but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
from gcp import get_key

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = get_key()

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1')
project_id = 'test-buckets'

service_account = 'projects/xxxxxxx/serviceAccounts/test-delete@test-buckets.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

request = service.projects().delete(name=service_account, body={})
response = request.execute()

pprint(response)
```

Output:

```
ssh://xxxx@x.x.x.x:22/home/xxxx/venv/bin/python3.4 -u /home/xxxx/scratch2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/scratch2.py", line 13, in <module>
    request = service.projects().delete(name=service_account, body={})
  File "/home/xxxx/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 722, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "body"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was using the wrong API when building the service too.  Below is the corrected code:

```
service = discovery.build('iam', 'v1')
request = service.projects().serviceAccounts().delete(name=project_name)
response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little too late for an answer, but I think the only error in your code is that this line of code:

```
request = service.projects().delete(name=service_account, body={})
```

should in fact be like this:

```
request = service.projects().delete(name=service_account)
```

As you can see in the error you shared, `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "body"`, so `body` is not an accepted argument here. In any case, printing the response in `pprint(response)` will probably output nothing, as the response to a DELETE operation has no content.